# PHP Request.QueryString - $_GET with conditions not sure how to

Tags: php

I am not familiar with php and want to write a redirect script using php (The server I am working on does not support asp)

I think it needs to be something like this

```
<?php if ($_GET[id]; == 'test') {echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.test.com" />'} ?>
```

I want to send a query string like `http://www.domain.com?id=test` then the page should redirect to `http://www.test.com` or a query like `http://www.domain.com?id=example` and it shoud redirect to `http://www.theexamplesite.com`

Using javascript and classic asp I would have done it like this:

```
<% if (Request.QueryString("id") == 'test') { %><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.test.com" /><% } %>
<% if (Request.QueryString("id") == 'example') { %><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.theexamplesite.com" /><% } %>
```

Hope you can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

$targets = array(
  'test'    => 'http://www.test.com/',
  'example' => 'http://www.theexamplesite.com/',
);

if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($targets[$_GET['id']]))
{
  header('Location: '.$targets[$_GET['id']]);
  exit;
}
```

That way you have a good view of your configured redirects and are able to add / remove / update them easily !

Comment: Nice, but you should check whether `$_GET['id']` is set too!

Comment: I Like this solution best as it shows me the variables easily! - Thanks to ALL

Comment: Is it possible to open the site in a new window like target="_blank"

Comment: @Gerald no you can't, since all we're doing here is sending an HTTP header to the browser (nor could you using the meta html tag btw)

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error. It should be:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == 'test')
```

But for the actual redirect, you might want to use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET) {
    if($_GET['id'] === 'test') {
        header('Location: http://www.test.com');
    }
    else if($_GET['id'] === 'example') {
        header('Location: http://www.theexamplesite.com');
    }
}
```

Reference: [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: @Wookai: Thanks, I just was about to fix it :D

Comment: Thanks a million - I did this so far <?php if ($_GET['id'] == 'site') echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.site.com" />' ?>
<?php if ($_GET['id'] == 'site1') echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.site1.com" />' ?> and it seems to work

Comment: @Gerald Ferreira: Yep, but using `header` is the cleaner way I would say.

Comment: I will test your solution just now as it looks more elegant!

Comment: The `array_key_exists` is unnecessary bloat here. First, a `$_GET["id"]` can be an empty string or NULL at worst. Hence key presence testing is dumb, an `isset()` is sufficient. But PHP also is a dynamic and weakly typed language, an unset/NULL value will be interpreted as empty string or false. You only need `isset` if you keep debugging notices enabled on your production server.

Comment: @mario: Yes you are right, `isset` would lead to the same results here, but the *meaning* is different... I'd say this is a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
<?php

if ($_GET[id] == 'test') {
    header('Location: http://www.test.com');
}
else {
    // real output
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This just looks like a target for exploitation.  Make sure you do some validation on the value of $_GET['id'] before you start redirecting the users.  If someone does http://www.domain.com?id=http://www.maliciouswebsite.com, will your script take them there?

Just be careful with redirects and do a lot of input validation.

Comment: It should not I think: I am writing this to hide affiliate links to not pass Page Rank to the sites I am promoting: the id will equal a value that I pre setup: If value = 1 redirect to site 1 if value 2 redirect to site 2 - so if you put malicious site it is not defined and should not work

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why were not accomplish the task given that you have ASP/JavaScript knowledge. Just tweak your asp script a little bit:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["id"] == 'test')
    {
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.test.com" />
        <?php
    }
    if ($_GET["id"] == 'example')
    {
        ?>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.theexamplesite.com" />
        <?php
    }
?>
```

There are other constructs available to do the same job such as [`switch...case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) or the [`?:`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator. The `?:` operator can shorten up your code quite a bit:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<?php echo $_GET['id'] == 'test' ? 'http://www.test.com' : 'http://www.theexamplesite.com'; ?>" />
```

Comment: I Think I struggled with the $_GET function - Thanks for the tip