# How to know which member chosen from list and display correct information (SQL/PHP/JS)

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I have a database with members whose names are being displayed in a list on my page. Each member name is a link that will take the user to a new page which displays information about that chosen member. I have the files `data.php`, `members.php` and `profiles.php`

Here is the code to fetch members from database (data.php):

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM members";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql.error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($j=0; $j<$rows; $j++){
echo '<li><a href="profiles.php">' . mysql_result($result,$j, 'name') . '</a></li>';
}
```

Javascript (members.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("data.php", function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
});
</script>
```

HTML (members.php):

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<p>Search for members of QRFC.</p>
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-filter="true" id="result">
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

So the names are being displayed correctly and now I'd like my page `profiles.php` to display the member information. I'm at a standstill and not sure where to begin.

A kick in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to do the following:

1 - When you fetch the members, also fetch their member id (assuming you have one).  If not, I guess you can use their names assuming those are unique.

2 - Add that id to your a href link: `<a href="profiles.php?memberId=' . mysql_result($result,$j, 'memberid') . '">`

3 - On your profiles.php page, request that memberId -- here is a post about requesting variables in php pages: [PHP Request.QueryString - $_GET with conditions not sure how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546374/php-request-querystring-get-with-conditions-not-sure-how-to)

4 - Finally query your database for additional information about the user requested.

Hope this helps get you started.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your members.php file works well enough as it is.

data.php (cleaned up your syntax to be less complex)

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM members";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql.error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
  echo '<li><a href="profiles.php?memberId=' . urlencode($row['name']) . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
endwhile;
```

**Important note**: When passing strings via query string, use `urlencode` and `urldecode`, respectively.

profiles.php (At least the query retrieval part)

```
$name = urldecode(trim($_GET['memberId'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberId = '$name'";
```

**Another Note**: If you are passing IDs to retrieve records from a database, it's best to use a numerical value instead of text. This helps reduce sql injections. There is a lot more to learn here, but you have to start somewhere.

Comment: You can't explicitly `urldecode` data coming from `$_GET`, it's already done, and double-decoding will yield errors.

Comment: That is something I did not know. Is this a configuration option like magic quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Pass user id in url :

```
echo '<li><a href="profiles.php?memberId=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></li>';
```

And on profiles.php file make query like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberId = '".$_GET['memberId']."'";
$result = mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

And after that as you know while loop for fetch member information...